# Use PHP Variable according to Select DropDown

Tags: php, jquery, forms, onchange

I am trying to change to which php variable to use according to Select Dropdown selection.
I am aware of how to change the value using jQuery .change but in this case as I am using a variable and php runs on page load and have nothing to do with jquery so I am using two variables but do not know how to use, please help.

Below are the two php variables:

```
$str201 = '21|'.$paygate_id.'|'.$name.'|'.$amount.'|'.$currency.'|'.$return_url.'|'.$transaction_date.'|'.$start_date.'|'.$end_date.'|201|NO||'.$key;
$str202 = '21|'.$paygate_id.'|'.$name.'|'.$amount.'|'.$currency.'|'.$return_url.'|'.$transaction_date.'|'.$start_date.'|'.$end_date.'|202|NO||'.$key;
```

Select DropDown

```
<select name="selectFrequency" id="selectFrequency">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="201">1</option>
  <option value="202">2</option>
</select>
```

Hidden Input of which I need to change php variable on select change:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUM" value="'.md5($str).'">
```

Comment: If you want to interact back with PHP from the client-side, you'll have to fire off an AJAX request

Comment: Can you please send me example code for this. I am not much familiar with AJAX :(

Comment: Tim,Can't we simply change the variable with jquery as we are running two different variables for two selections.

What you say ?

Comment: Better use ajax to change the value.. You need to use on change ajax call. send the selected value via data and then get response as the value..

Comment: @Ganesh : Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: 'Hidden Input of which I need to change php variable on select change:' what are you trying to do here??

Comment: @HimanshuJain I have shown the method of doing your problem using AJAX in answer. If you need any clarifications, please feel free to comment it under my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data attrib to the options, containing the MD5 hash of the variable you need to pass via CHECKSUM.

```
<select name="selectFrequency" id="selectFrequency">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="201" data-checksum="'. md5($str201). '">1</option>
  <option value="202" data-checksum="'. md5($str202). '">2</option>
</select>
```

On select change just update the hidden input with this value

EDIT:

To update:

```
$('#selectFrequency').change(function() {

 $('input[name=CHECKSUM]').val($('#selectFrequency :selected').data('checksum'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To interact back with the server-side code, you'll need to make an AJAX call. So, attach a change event to your select, and fire the AJAX:

```
$("#selectFrequency").change(function() {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourPHP.php", //Leave this out to call the same page
        type: "POST", //is this actually a post?
        data: {yourData : selectedValue} //Send your data in a key/val object
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); //your PHP response
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tim, I have both the variables and the form in one php file than how I will define yourphp.php ?

Comment: Ahh, remove the URL param, that will post it back to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple demonstration of ajax call. You can modify it for your use. I think you can use md5() in server side PHP

HTML & SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectFrequency").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "script.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {selected : selected},
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data); 
        }
    });
});
});
</script>

<select name="selectFrequency" id="selectFrequency">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="201">1</option>
  <option value="202">2</option>
</select>
```

script.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['selected'];
?>
```